# how to fill field values using ajax in yii2?

Tags: ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using **ajax** in **yii2**.
How to fill fields without submit form. Without submitting the validation is working, but how to add field value.
In below code `$this->name` is my field name.

```
if($this->statusOk){
    $this->name = "gana";
}else{
    return $this->addError('branch_code', ' code can’t be found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set your value in save function(in model) or before saving your model(in controller) ,and use custom validation just for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,custom ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on("blur", "#id", function () {
            var data = $("#nameField").val();
            $.ajax({
                url    : "validURL",
                type   : "post",
                data   : {"sortcode":data},
                success: function (response) 
                {
                 var json_obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                 if(json_obj.errorMessage) {
                  // do something
                 }else {
                 // do something
                 }
```

Comment: thank u,but i don't want like this,but i get another idea from your answer